# Any downsides or security risks with set_include_path?

Tags: php, include, include-path

Ok, to start with - I am addicted to using a root relative link structure for everything. Include in php always makes that difficult for me, but I happened upon a line of code that lets me include root-relatively.

It's really simple:

```
set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] );
```

That's from a comment in the php manual

I have a pretty simple php site, but with many different subdirectories, and this makes it easy to use. Also - the company may be switching servers soon, and I am thinking this may ease the transition for many sites.

So is there a security risk here? I don't dynamically include files or remotely include them.  Am I taking a performance hit including this at the top of every php file? or is it negligible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no security risk as long as you control what you put in the `include_path`.

There is, however, a performance hit if you have too many paths in your `include_path` (as PHP will have to try each path before finding the file).

Comment: If you have to add a lot of paths to the include path put the most common paths at the front because it searches the paths in order.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, the docroot is at the end of the `include_path`, so you'll only see a performance hit when an included file isn't found in the rest of the `include_path` (ie a missing file).